# silencing Wunused-variable for gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

This is my code:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
//__attribute__((unused))
static int myVar = 5;
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

and when compiled with `-Wall` I get the warning. But when I use the attribute I don't get it.

Why doesnt the pragma stuff work? I get no warning for an unrecognized flag. Other stackoverflow threads pointed me to the pragma stuff...

using `gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 5.3.0`

**EDIT:**
I read in the gcc docs this:

> ## pragma GCC diagnostic kind option
>
> Modifies the disposition of a diagnostic. Note that not all diagnostics are modifiable; at the moment only warnings (normally controlled by ‘-W...’) can be controlled, and not all of them. Use -fdiagnostics-show-option to determine which diagnostics are controllable and which option controls them.

but I still don't understand how to know if a warning can be suppressed with a pragma - even if I get `[-Wunused-variable]` from the output...

Comment: I can repro the main problem with GCC 5.3.0 built on Mac OS X.  Adding `-Wno-unused-variable` on the command line suppresses the warning.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler try adding ```-fno-diagnostics-show-option``` and you will see the difference. ```-fdiagnostics-show-option``` seems to be on by default and without it we will just get warnings and no hint which the warning actually is (```[-Wunused-variable]```)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's the gcc doc's fault...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having appears to be that the warnings about unused variables are emitted once the entire compilation unit has been processed, rather than at the point of declaration. Therefore, having the warning suppression active over the point of declaration does nothing at all, and when you then pop it away, the warning is un-ignored at the point where it actually matters; that is, after the end of the file.

Removing the `push` and `pop` directives does make the warning suppressed. Also, when moving the `diagnostic ignored` directive to the end of the file, the warning remains suppressed.

Comment: lol - this sounds broken - is it worth a report to the gcc folks? unfortunately I cannot leave the diagnostic unpop-ed because I am writing a library... thanks for the investigation

Comment: @onqtam: Why is the context of this being a library relevant to leaving the diagnostic unpopped? As long as this file is a separate compilation unit, the diagnostics state will not affect other compilation units.

Comment: As for being broken, it's a matter of definition, I'd say, but by all means do report it. It may well be that noone has simply bothered defining it.

Comment: I'm writing a header only library that is supposed to be included in every compilation unit. Anyway - I'm not gonna bother with reporting it - if anyone else is up for the task - go for it.

Comment: Interesting.  Removing the last line of the code does indeed allow the code to compile without the warning.  At one level it makes sense (it isn't until the end of the file that it can tell that the variable is unused).  At another, it is probably a (minor) defect in the implementation; it should be an attribute associated with the variables declared while the pragma is in effect.

Comment: @onqtam: If your header-only library is going to define unused static variables in each object module that uses your library, your library is probably not going to be very popular.  You'd have to talk hard and fast to persuade me that it is a good idea, at any rate.  I wouldn't say you can't be successful — but you would have to explain what you're doing and why.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm writing a testing library with auto-registering tests. To do that I use anonymous global variables that get initialized by a function on program startup - and that is how I register the tests. Other testing frameworks with self-registering tests do the same - like [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch). And these variables are needed just to trigger code execution before entering ```main()``` and are not used after that...

Comment: OK; that's probably reason enough — though I'm still not quite sure why the variables are unused if they're used.  It's also a somewhat different type of library from what I was thinking of.